# How to give a POST API request in a browser?

Tags: java, api, post, put

I'm really new to APIs and POST or PUT or DELETE. I'm also new to running APIs using POST or other. 
I have given a document which says

Function :- Add new Item

URI :- qtp/qtps

ACTION :- POST

```
REQUEST :- <n1:qtp xmlns:n1="http://www.mac.com/qts/xml/ns/qtm/qtpManagement"><name>rosa     qtp 3</name><ipAddress>171.68.121.232</ipAddress><macAddress>10:0t:24:03:r7:57</macAddress><description>this is rosa qtp </description></n1:qtp>
```

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed further, But I know that by executing the request I need to Add a new Item in the application server, I tried something with browser myself but it did not work.

Can someone show me how can I work with this or explain me more about this or at-least give me a clue

Answer (score 1):

One of the most useful tools for testing and debugging HTTP requests, in my experience, is cURL (http://curl.haxx.se/).

cURL is actually the under-the-hood library used for HTTP requests by a majority of PHP  apps; the command-line version lets you do virtually anything that HTTP can do, and get great debugging data.

In the scenario you describe above, after downloading and installing cURL you'd likely use a command like:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/xml" --data '<XML YOU WANT TO SEND>' -X POST <URL TO WHICH DATA SHOULD BE SENT>
```

It's not clear from your question what the destination host+url is, but using the specific sample data you provide this would probably look like:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/xml"  --data '<n1:qtp xmlns:n1="http://www.mac.com/qts/xml/ns/qtm/qtpManagement"><name>rosa     qtp 3</name><ipAddress>171.68.121.232</ipAddress><macAddress>10:0t:24:03:r7:57</macAddress><description>this is rosa qtp </description></n1:qtp>' -X POST http://www.mac.com/qtp/qtps
```

Answer (score 0):

Install a firebug plugin for that. You can use SOA client.